# How to construct a .sql dump file from stored disk path /var/lib/postgresql/data

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, pg-dump, wal

We have a snapshot disk of a previously running `postgresql` server on a kubernetes cluster ( that is no longer running), we would like to create a new cluster with the existing snapshot disk,

We first created a disk and linked it to a `pvc` as persistent volume,
a `pvc` that is attached to the new `postgresql` deployment

We have all `data` and `wal` files in path `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Starting the `postgresql` helm chart with the pvc fails to load the database

```
FATAL:  requested timeline 29 is not a child of this server's history
[XX000] DETAIL:  Latest checkpoint is at 3040/8A000028 on timeline 28, but in the history of the requested timeline, the server forked off from that timeline at 303F/B10000A0
```

we tried reseting the wal with `pg_resetwal` but with no success

```bash
pg_resetwal -f /varl/lib/postgresql/data
```

We are now looking to construct a `.sql` file to dump to database,

is there a way to construct a dump `.sql` file from data path `/var/lib/postgresql/data` ?

Comment: No there is not. You need a running instance to create a dump file.